# How do you handle sensitive data in Go?

Tags: string, security, go, garbage-collection

Sorry if this has been asked before!

**Background**:
I am currently working on an API in Go that generates access-tokens which will be used to expose a few APIs our company is currently using internally. Think about tokens you use for the Stripe or Github. I'm making something like that :). I generate a token, hash it, and then persist it.

**Problem**:
As far as I know, strings in Go are immutable. I used to be a Java engineer. Strings in Java are immutable as well and live in something called a string constant pool. Anyway, in Java your string lives on the heap until the garbage collector runs. So instead of using a string, it's better to go with a char-array for something like a password or an API-token.

How does this work in Go? Is the string representing my API-tokens alive on the heap until garbage collection? Can someone hijack my heap and grab the token? Should I be using something else instead of a string? Maybe like a rune-slice? Can I force garbage collection of my immutable string?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: The Go standard library uses `[]byte` for keys.

Comment: I may be naive, but how would one go about hijacking heap memory from an application written in Go or Java?

Comment: @kingkupps you want to keep sensitive data around as short as possible. Check out the official oracle docs about sensitive data: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#PBEEx

Comment: @MuffinTop ahh really. I will do some googling. Thanks!

Comment: Any sensitive data, even if it is garbage collected, will stay in memory until it is overwritten. Someone cannot hijack your heap, but a side channel attack can reveal memory contents, or the page can be swapped out. If you're worried about these, use []byte and overwrite it once you're done with it. There was a go library that locks pages in memory so they are not swapped out, you might want to search that as well.

Comment: @kingkupps,  no, reading memory does not require compromising the host. Do you remember [Spectre](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability))? [Meltdown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability))? [Rowhammer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer)? RCE is enough, and in virtualized environments you also have to consider malicious neighbors. "I don't know how to exploit this, therefore I don't have to worry about it" is not a good attitude.

Comment: Burak and Peter thank you both for the correction and explanation. I've deleted my comment but I want to clarify that my intent was not to say "don't worry about it". Seems like there is strong rationale for why sensitive data is still at risk of abuse even without persisting or logging it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments posted to my question I ended up using a `[]byte` to handle my sensitive data. I clear the array when I am done using it.

My concern was that a side channel attack could be used to get access to string objects while they are still on the heap.